# onclick overlay with center position

Tags: javascript, overlay, positioning

below my javascript. I want to when I click then overlay background and window will be center position.

```
function openPopupManager(url)
{
  var url;
  url = "child_upload_gallery_images.php?make_id="+$('#make_id').val()+"&model_id="+$('#model_id').val()+"&model_sub_cat_id="+$('#model_sub_cat_id').val()+"&gallery_id="+$('#gallery_id').val()+"&wheel_id="+$('#wheel_id').val();
  mywindow = window.open (url,"Gallery Images.","location=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,width=800,height=600");
  mywindow.moveTo(0,0);
  return false;
}
```

this is html

```
  <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $button;?>" id="upload_gallery_img" value="Upload Selected Gallery Image" class="subtn" onclick="javascript:openPopupManager();" />
```

I am trying but can't figure out yet.. still trying. popup window opening but overlay and center how?

Answer (score 0):

To center you could use something like this to get the screen width and height.

```
var popupWidth=800;
var popupHeight=600;
var posX=window.screen.availWidth/2-popupWidth/2;
var posY=window.screen.availHeight/2-popHeight/2;
myWindow.moveTo(posX,posY);
```

I'm not quite sure what you mean by the overlay won't work. If you want the window to be active you can add `myWindow.focus();`.

Comment: @AccoreLTD I don't see anything about an overlay in your code?

Comment: @qw3n... i have no idea where i can add that.. that what i mean i can't figure out where i can add that code and how to do that